# Family of continuous functions seperates points

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $f_i: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $i \in I$ where $Χ$ is second countable and $f_i$ are continuous $\forall i \in I$. Then the family $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ is separating the points of $X$?

If $X$ was normal space we could apply Urysohn's Lemma, but here $X$ is second countable (and consequently separable).

Any ideas would be helpful

Comment: Suppose $\{f_i\}$ consisted of just constant functions or something like that? I think $f_i$ must have more structure on it.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered if there is no further information about the family $(f_i)_i$.

Comment: These are all the conditions about $f_i$. If it doesn't hold, is there any counterexample?

Comment: A counterexample was mentioned in the first comment! Let $f_i(x)=0$.

Comment: Aren't you asked to prove that under certain conditions a separating family $(f_i)$ **exists**?

Comment: Thanks, it was so obvious to find a counterexample!

Answer (score 0):

For any space, if the $f_i$ happen to be all constant, or on $X=\mathbb{R}$ we take the functions $f(x) = A\sin(x), A \in \mathbb{R}$, say, we cannot separate all points of $X$. So you have to be careful about the family of functions.

There are demands on $X$ as well:

If $X$ is indiscrete (e.g.) then $X$ is second countable, and all continuous functions on $X$ with codomain $\mathbb{R}$ (or any Hausdorff space) are constant.

So **no** family of continuous functions on $X$ can separate the points.

$X$ is called functionally Hausdorff iff such a point-separating realvalued-continuous family of $X$ exists at all. Not all spaces are functionally Hausdorff, as we saw. Even $T_3$ spaces need not be.

A second countable regular $T_1$ space (which is normal so Urysohn applies) will have a (countable, even) family of this type.